# Naming conventions where models have more than one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models - users, books and contribution.

Each @book will have a title and an author (who owns that instance).

Optionally, each @book can have a number of contributors.

Authors and contributors come from the same class User.

What's the best approach to writing the model relationships? My instinct is

```
User  :name
Book  :title :user_id
Contribution  :book_id :user_id
```

users.rb -

```
has_many :books
has_many :books, through :contribution
```

books.rb -

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :users, through :contribution
```

contributions.rb -

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :book
```

...but this seems like asking for trouble. Is there a best practice approach to handling models with more than one relationship?

Comment: I'm not completely understanding the data. What is "contribution"? Is that another attribute of books? For example, book 1, written by John Smith, with contributions by Jane Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was the following -

users.rb -

```
has_many :books
has_many :contributions
```

books.rb -

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :contributions
```

contributions.rb -

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :book
```

- lesson for me: don't overthink stuff

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the full extent of the needs are of your site, but it can be even simpler and just make contributor an attribute of the books model. Books would just have an array of contributors the same way it has a name and an author.

If you have more complex things in mind for the contributor, then maybe making it it's own model is the way to go.

Comment: I want to be able to search on contributions a lot - would making the contribution type an array on the book model have an impact on the db?

Comment: You're probably right that it could be cleaner if there are a lot of contributors, and a lot of associations, that you should make it it's own model.